# How to do the "display part" of the mathematical calculations you can do with apache.commons.math3? Draw a curve, display (correctly) its equation

Tags: java, math

`apache.commons.math3` can do mathematical calculations.

But when the time comes to draw a curve in an orthonormal coordinate system, and to display correctly its equation as nicely as in a latex output, with correct symbols, it becomes hard.

For Java, I  only saw samples using *Java FX* or *Java Swing*, both reinventing the wheel from scratch all the time, and stopping far from succeeding in having only a flat tire, because that programming job is harder than believed, and both of them are absolutely not done for that...

What is the API that shall be used to display curves, mathematical equations, or do other mathematical/statistical drawings?

Comment: "In my days", we 1. dumped (any 1-3dim visualizable) "data" to a (plain) text file (with 1-3 columns and N rows), 2. Just `gnuplot out.txt` (to get a quick&configurable(exportable...) visual representation of that ) http://www.gnuplot.info/

Comment: Thanks! It's a great progress! I will study it: it's a very good beginning. But if is able to draw curves, it is writting: `sqrt(x**2 + 5) - 12` near them, not their readable formulas.

Comment: 101! - http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-functions/ :)

Comment: And how do you embed that gnu plotting results into a _Java_ program? Create a jpg for gnuplot output and displaying it, I think?

Comment: Yes, that was the "wheel" part: data/math -> (static) image (good for "scientific writing"/presentation etc.) ..if you want/need to "display" it in a modern java based (web/desktop) application (with action and hover and styles and "aero"..:), there exist probably "fancier tools" (e.g.) https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/

Comment: (web/desktop/*mobile*:)